# awk: set a variable if the conditions doesn't meet

Tags: awk

I'm trying to remove all lines which have a duplicate first column entry and the first column is shorter than a specific length. I'm using the code below for that.

```
awk -F':' '!seen[$1]++ && length($1)<=32' file-dup > file
```

**Test sample:** (this is done with matching number of characters to 10 instead of 32.)

**Input:**

```
a:123:addf
ab:123:addf
a:123:addf
abc:123:addf
akjsalkdjalkd123:addf
abc:123:addf
afj:123:addf
aki:123:addf
aop:123:addf
aop:123:addf
akijh:123:addf
akijhkjsladjslkajdlkad:123:addf
```

**Output:**

```
a:123:addf
ab:123:addf
abc:123:addf
afj:123:addf
aki:123:addf
aop:123:addf
akijh:123:addf
```

This basically outputs all the lines which matches the condition.

But whether all the lines matches the condition or not, the return code is always 0 as `awk` is successfully executed.

I want to know whether any line in the file didn't match the condition or all lines met the condition. Like when the input is as below, I want to return a different value or set some variable because none of the lines meets the condition.

```
a:123:addf
ab:123:addf
abc:123:addf
afj:123:addf
aki:123:addf
aop:123:addf
akijh:123:addf
```

I can basically check the line numbers of the original file and the new file and get the answer. but

Is it possible to return a different return code in case the condition didn't match or may be set a variable inside the `awk` itself if the conditions didn't meet?

Comment: Could you please do add samples of input and expected output to clarify your problem, kindly do edit your post and let us  know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added test sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try, I didn't test though:

```
awk -F':' '!seen[$1]++ && length($1)<=32{c++;print $0 > "file"}END{print NR==c}' file-dup
```

- used `print >` to redirect to the target file (`file`)
- the command return 1 (all lines are matching the condition) or 0

You can also don't do any change on your awk command, and fire the 2nd command to compare the two files (file and file-dup) to determine if there are some lines filtered out.

Comment: it's working as expected. Here we are comparing the two files after the operation. isn't it?
is there a way without re-opening the files, it can be done?
this is good and working for a smaller file. But in case of larger files, comparing two files afterwards will be an extra overhead.

Comment: No @RatDon , the awk command doesn't compare the two files, instead, it compares the variable `c` and the number of lines in your `file-dup`

Comment: Okay. understood.

Comment: UNIX commands don't "return" anything, they produce output and set an exit status. Your current code outputs 1  or 0 in the END, having it exit with status 1 or 0 would be more appropriate (`exit (NR==c)` or `exit (NR!=c)`, whichever produces a `0` when the result means "success" to the OP). Given that, `print $0 > "file"` can just be `print` and the OP can redirect the actual output outside of awk as is typically done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the exit instruction of AWK at the end to control the exit code:

```
awk -F':' '{if (!seen[$1]++ && length($1)<=10) print; else r=1}END{exit r}' file-dup > file
```

Demo:

```sh
$ awk -F':' '{if (!seen[$1]++ && length($1)<=10) print; else r=1}END{exit r}' file-dup && echo OK || echo KO
a:123:addf
ab:123:addf
abc:123:addf
afj:123:addf
aki:123:addf
aop:123:addf
akijh:123:addf
KO
$ awk -F':' '{if (!seen[$1]++ && length($1)<=10) print; else r=1}END{exit r}' file && echo OK || echo KO
a:123:addf
ab:123:addf
abc:123:addf
afj:123:addf
aki:123:addf
aop:123:addf
akijh:123:addf
OK
```